# CXF/Spring Injecting Top-Level Service Name and Namespace into JAX-WS Interface

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, cxf

I'm flying a CXF-based Web service not unsimilar to the example on the CXF Web site at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html . This service has an implemented endpoint based on the following sample context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:endpoint id="myServiceMembersImpl"
        implementor="#myService"
        endpointName="e:MyServiceMembersEndpoint"
        serviceName="s:MyServiceMembersService"
        address="http://localhost:8080/myservicemembers"
        xmlns:e="http://localhost:8080/myservicemembers/ns"
        xmlns:s="http://localhost:8080/myservicemembers/ns"/>

</beans>
```

Then, of course, there is the Java ...

Interface:

```
package com.me.service;

@WebService
public interface MyService {

String MEMBER = "MEMBER";

@WebResult(name = MEMBER)
Member getMember(@WebParam(name = "memberId") long memberId) throws Exception;
     // ... 
     // more interface declarations 
     // ... 

} // end interface
```

and, implementation:

```
package com.me.service.impl;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.me.service.MyService")
@Path("/")
public class MyServiceMembersImpl implements MyService {

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes({ APP_JSON, APP_XML })
@Produces({ APP_JSON, APP_XML })
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Member getMember(@PathParam("id") final long memberId) throws Exception {

        // ... 
        // business logic 
        // ... 
        return theMember; 

     } // end method 

} // end class
```

Which returns a WSDL that starts somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<wsdl:definitions name="MyServiceImplService" 
    targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/myservicemembers/ns" 
    xmlns:ns1="**http://service.me.com/**" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/myservicemembers/ns" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/myservicemembers?wsdl=**MyService**.wsdl" 
        namespace="**http://service.me.com/**" /> 
        <wsdl:binding name="MyServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:**MyService**">
<!-- ... --> 
</wsdl:definitions>
```

It's fairly simple using the "jaxws:endpoint" element in the application context to change the settings for the endpoint. This fleshes out the service name, endpoint name and other fields. However, the top-level interface still has a say in the WSDL file. The **STARRED** items above are from the top-level interface. **How can I inject values into the top-level interface for the targetNamespace and serviceName?**

My good reasons for doing this include (1) not wanting to expose package names in the WSDL and (2) wanting to switch namespaces as an application moves down a deployment runway. Thus I cannot use annotations since those are compile-time values, I can't substitute them with property placeholders, and I will not recompile my code in the production tier.

Comment: I'm open to any solutions, including static blocks and direct accessors, as long as they can be set with property substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by programmatically creating the services using [JaxWsServerFactoryBean](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/JaxWsServerFactoryBean.html) instead of using `<jaxws:endpoint>` in your Spring config.   Doing the creation programmatically gives you a lot more control.

For example:

```
@Autowired
var myServiceImpl: MyService = _

val propMap = mutable.HashMap[String, AnyRef]("org.apache.cxf.logging.FaultListener"->faultListener.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])

val sf = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean
sf.setServiceBean(myServiceImpl)
sf.setAddress("/myservice")
sf.setServiceName(new QName(WEB_SERVICE_NAMESPACE, "myService", "MyService"))
sf.setProperties(propMap)
sf.create
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this information. I am looking at this. I wanted to post this link, which I think completes the picture of a CXF non-Spring implementation: http://www.axlrosen.net/stuff/cxf-without-spring.html .